# Ruby send mail with smtp

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, smtp

I'm trying to send simple email via Ruby (no rails) on OS X, with XCode (which installs Ruby.) But I'm running into a problem with my smtp server which requires the email client to check mail before sending as a form of authentication.

How can I get Ruby to authenticate with the smtp server in a "POP" fashion before I can send mail? Not download mail; I only want to send html formatted email (eventually via Applescript calling Ruby, because Applescript doesn't support smtp), but the server requires that I check mail before I send.

**Edit 4/05/10:**

Well, that's embarrasing. Turned out to be simpler; I was trying to make it more complex than it needed to be. Even though my mail server requires pop before smtp, this sends OK:

```
require 'net/smtp'

message = <<MESSAGE_END
    From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
    To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
    Subject: SMTP e-mail test

    This is a test e-mail message.
    MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('mail.mydomain.com', 25) do |smtp|
smtp.send_message message,
            'mark@mydomain.com',
            'mark@mydomain.com'
end
```

**Edit 4/04/10:**

With this I get a 500 unrecognized command error; the pop server is responding, though.

```
require 'net/smtp'
require 'net/pop'

message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

Net::POP3.start('mail.mydomain.com', 110, 'mark@mydomain.com', 'password') do |pop|

// If this line is included,
// I get a printout of the number
// of emails on the server
// right before the error:
//
// puts pop.n_mails  end

Net::SMTP.start('mail.markratledge.com', 
                25, 
                'localhost', 
                'mark@mydomain.com', 'password', :plain) do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message message, 'mark@mydomain.com', 
                             'mark@mydomain.com'
end
end
```

Comment: Why are you requiring a pop check if pop isn't available on the smtp server?

Comment: My mistake; I meant to say secure pop....

Comment: I suspect the reason for the 500 error when doing `pop.finish` is that if you pass a block to `POP3.start` as you're doing above then the connection is automatically closed for you at the end of the block so by putting in a `pop.close` you're trying to close the connection twice.

Comment: The 4/05/10 edit probably works because you can send email to yourself without authentication. It's likely only relaying to other domains that requires the POP before SMTP.

Comment: You're right; it doesn't work for other domains. Still tweaking and getting closer with using POP to login to the server before smtp; now I get a "SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POP before SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP) isn't one of the authentication types supported by `Net::SMTP` so I think you're going to have to use [Net::POP3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/index.html) to do your POP3 login e.g.

```
require 'net/pop'
pop = Net::POP3.start(addr, port, account, password)
pop.finish
```

`Net::POP3` is in the Standard Library so should be available anywhere that `Net::SMTP` is.

Comment: Getting closer. With the code above I get a 200 reply code that the pop server is ready. (Obviously I'm just learning Ruby...)

Comment: the `start` should connect to the server and log you in. Try inserting a `puts pop.n_mails` after the `POP3.start` - this should print the number of messages in the mail box as a diagnostic that you're definitely talking to the POP server. Also try doing the `pop.finish` before making your SMTP connection. What happens now if you actually try to **send** a message via SMTP?

Comment: No luck with moving pop.finish; still a 500 error. And still can't send at all via SMTP without first checking for email. But I can login to the pop server with the code snip above.

Comment: At the moment you're doing your `Net::SMTP.start` from inside the `Net::POP3.start` block. What if you move it outside? Do you get a descriptive message with the 500 error giving any clues?

Comment: Updated code; I was trying to make things too complex. Thanks for your help over the last few days.

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't make your server happy then Net::Telnet will let you send the raw commands yourself.

Comment: I don't have telnet access to my server; only ssh.

Comment: If you open a telnet connection on the appropriate port numbers (110 for POP and 25 for SMTP) then you can send raw commands.

Comment: I checked again and you're both right; I do have telent access. I thought from the past telnet was disabled on this shared host. Eventually, the Ruby script will be called from an Applescript in order to send html formatted email, so telnet is handy to test the pop server, but can telnet recieve html formatted email?

Comment: I don't think you understood me at all. I was suggesting that you telnet into port 25 and send your own SMTP commands, not login to a telnet daemon.

Comment: I pretty much did; I can telnet to port 25 and HELO and talk to the server that way, but I'm going to keep trying to work with the pop and smtp code above before I try the Ruby telnet include.